# Gathering Outlook shared mailbox permissions with Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am trying to see what accounts might have access to another account's mailbox with powershell.

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity <UPN>
```

will show me, from an individual account, who else has access. I want to be able to see external access, from a single UPN.
Results come like this:

```
| Identity      | User              | AccessRights               |
|:-------------:|:-----------------:|:--------------------------:|
|sum1@domain.com| NT AUTHORITY\SELF |{FullAccess, ReadPermission}|
|sum1@domain.com|AnnOther@domain.com|{FullAccess}                |
```

but if I look at the Ann's permissions:

```
| Identity          | User            | AccessRights               |
|:-----------------:|:---------------:|:--------------------------:|
|AnnOther@domain.com|NT AUTHORITY\SELF|{FullAccess, ReadPermission}|
```

I would like to be able to get a list of all users Ann has access to, without needing to know what that account is beforehand.

Comment: As this information is stored in the target mailboxes you will have to query the permissions of all mailboxes. This could take a long time depending on the organization you are in.

Answer (score 1):

As TomG said, you'll have to list all mailboxes and filter to the user you want. I tested this and it's pretty slow, but I'm not aware of a better way.

Example:

```
Get-EXOMailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -ResultSize:Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | Where-Object {($_.user -like '*@*')}
```